# Xcode Swift Language Version, different between unspecified and version?

Tags: swift, xcode, build

I could not find any clear explanation and I really wonder what is the main reason if we set ***"Swift Language Version"*** as unspecified.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Unspecified Swift Language Version used for backward compatibility. Lets say we have a project written on Swift 2, but Xcode 10 does not support this version of Swift. In this case the Swift Language Version will be `unspecified` and you should set any supported version.